# How can I convert a const char* to a string in CLR/C++ with FLTK to obtain the value of an FL_Input or other widget?

Tags: c++, c, fltk

I have been recently constructing a program. The end goal is to get what the user has written in the Fl_Input box and write it into my database. To do this I am going to need a callback on a button that allows me to at least get the string value of an Fl_Input->value()

The expected results is that the contents of the Fl_Input will be outputted in the console window (but eventually they will be written to a database). The actual results that I am getting is an error code stating that the program is trying to write to secure/corrupted memory it is not too clear so I will paste below

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Start.exe
>   Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

As eventually I would like to have multiple of these Fl_Inputs as strings and store them in some sort of vector I will leave that part of the code in as well but it is commented.

```
struct Info
{
    // The widgets
    Fl_Input* instr;
    Fl_Int_Input* inint;

    // Saved values
    char sval[40];
    int  ival;
};

// Callback for the done button
void done_cb(Fl_Widget* w, void* param)
{
    Info* input = reinterpret_cast<Info*>(param);

    // Get the values from the widgets
    //const char* l = input->instr->value();
    //auto my_cstr = l;
    //std::string s(my_cstr);

    strcpy_s(input->sval, input->instr->value());
    input->ival = atoi(input->inint->value());

    // Print the values
    printf("String value is %s\n", input->sval);
    printf("Integer value is %d\n", input->ival);
}

void signupScreen (void) {
    //Fl_Input *fname, *lname, *username, *password, *dob;
    //Fl_Window *w = new Fl_Window(800, 800, "signup");
    //fname = new Fl_Input(200, 100, 500, 30, "Enter first name:");
    //lname = new Fl_Input(200, 150, 500, 30, "Enter last name:");
    //username = new Fl_Input(200, 200, 500, 30, "Enter username wanted:");
    //password = new Fl_Input(200, 250, 500, 30, "Enter password wanted:");
    //dob = new Fl_Input(200, 300, 500, 30, "Enter date of birth in format dd/mm/yyyy:");
    //std::vector<std::string> v; //= { string(fname->value()), string(lname->value()), string(username->value()), string(password->value()), string(dob->value()) };
    Info input;

    // Create the window
    Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(200, 150);
    int x = 50, y = 10, w = 100, h = 30;
    input.instr = new Fl_Input(x, y, w, h, "Str");
    input.instr->tooltip("String input");

    y += 35;
    input.inint = new Fl_Int_Input(x, y, w, h, "Int");
    input.inint->tooltip("Integer input");

    y += 35;
    Fl_Button* done = new Fl_Button(x, y, 100, h, "Done");
    done->callback(done_cb, &input);
    window->end();


    window->show();

}
```

EDIT: Remove line of code

Comment: There aren't any C++/CLR strings in the code you have posted.  To convert as per your title, have a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/311259/how-to-convert-from-system-string-to-char-in-visual-c.

Comment: Okay I will edit the tag and the title it is there because their will be as this is a sign up form that uses CLR to interact with a database.

EDIT: the link posted is for converting string to char*. I want the reverse. As I have solved this part of the problem if you wish to help I refer you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441540/fltk-getting-value-from-input-on-button-release?rq=1

If you have any questions as to how I solved this problem please feel free to send me a message @cup

- NP00

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your `Info` object is going out of scope (since it is allocated on the stack) before the callback.  Try making it static/global instead.